# Postgresql Week number same for Jan and Dec dates

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, week-number

In PostgreSQL, I am trying to convert timestamps into week numbers using the query below.

```
select user_id, 
time_stamp, 
date(time_stamp), 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_stamp) as Year, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time_stamp) as Month, 
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM time_stamp) as Week
from user_engagement

 user_id |     time_stamp      |    date    | year | month | week 
---------+---------------------+------------+------+-------+------
    6282 | 2013-01-01 14:29:35 | 2013-01-01 | 2013 |     1 |    1
    6282 | 2013-01-02 14:29:35 | 2013-01-02 | 2013 |     1 |    1
    6282 | 2013-12-30 14:29:35 | 2013-12-30 | 2013 |    12 |    1
    6282 | 2013-12-31 14:29:35 | 2013-12-31 | 2013 |    12 |    1
```

I am surprised to see that the week numbers of the dates in Jan and Dec of the year 2013 are the same. Could someone explain the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html) explains this pretty well:

> week
>
> The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By
>   definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year
>   contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of
>   a year is in week 1 of that year.
>
> In the ISO week-numbering system, it is possible for early-January
>   dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and
>   for late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year.
>   For example, 2005-01-01 is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and
>   2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while 2012-12-31 is
>   part of the first week of 2013. It's recommended to use the isoyear
>   field together with week to get consistent results.